# ScalaMock. Mock a class that takes arguments

Tags: unit-testing, scala, mocking, scalatest

Full disclosure: I'm very new to mocking and mocking frameworks. I'm trying to use ScalaMock because it seemed like the 'default' mocking framework to use with ScalaTest but I am happy to use any other framework which is compatible with ScalaTest.

The problem: I've written in Scala a class that talks to a socket. The class has a type parameter of what sort of socket it is to talk to and one of it's arguments is a factory for creating sockets of that type. It has the signature:

```
class XScanner[T <: SocketClient](
  confPath: String = "/etc/default/configPath",
  socketClientFactory: String => T
) extends ScannerBase(path)
```

I would like to be able to write unit tests for this class by supplying a mock SocketClient so my test code doesn't have to connect to a real socket but I can't work out how to do this with ScalaMock.

My test code looks like this:

```
val t = new XScanner[SocketClient](confPath, (s: String) => mock[SocketClient])
```

Clearly that won't compile because `SocketClient` expects a path to the socket as an argument but I can't call `mock[SocketClient(s)]` because that's not a type and I can't call `mock[SocketClient](s)` because mock doesn't take the arguments of the type passed to it as it's own arguments.

So how can I write a mock `SocketClient` factory to pass to my Scanner? I can't even work out how to mock a class that takes arguments!

Comment: I'm the author of ScalaMock. Which version of Scala and which version of ScalaMock are you using? The answers are different for ScalaMock2 versus ScalaMock3.

Comment: Scala Mock 3 with Scala 2.10.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The insight is that what you need to mock is `socketClientFactory`. And then set it up to return a mock `SocketClient`.

Given:

```
trait SocketClient {
  def frobnicate(): Unit
}

class ScannerBase(path: String)

class XScanner[T <: SocketClient](
  confPath: String = "/etc/default/configPath",
  socketClientFactory: String => T
) extends ScannerBase(confPath) {
  val socket = socketClientFactory("Some Socket Name")
  socket.frobnicate
}
```

(side note - your default value for `confPath` can never be used because there's no default value for `socketClientFactory`).

then this should get you started (this is with Scala 2.9.x and ScalaMock2 - 2.10.x with ScalaMock3 will be slightly different, but not much so):

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalamock.generated.GeneratedMockFactory

class ScannerTest extends FunSuite with MockFactory with GeneratedMockFactory {

  test("scanner") {
    val mockFactory = mockFunction[String, SocketClient]
    val mockClient = mock[SocketClient]
    mockFactory.expects("Some Socket Name").returning(mockClient)
    mockClient.expects.frobnicate
    val scanner = new XScanner("path/to/config", mockFactory)
  }
}
```

For completeness, here's the same test in Scala 2.10.0 and ScalaMock3:

```
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory

class ScannerTest extends FunSuite with MockFactory {

  test("scanner") {
    val mockFactory = mockFunction[String, SocketClient]
    val mockClient = mock[SocketClient]
    mockFactory.expects("Some Socket Name").returning(mockClient)
    (mockClient.frobnicate _).expects()
    val scanner = new XScanner("path/to/config", mockFactory)
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this overcomes the fact that SocketClient takes 1 argument. I can't write:

val mockClient = mock[SocketClient]
mockFactory.expects("Some Socket Name").returning(mockClient)

Because mock[SocketClient] won't compile. Are you suggesting I modify SocketClient to take no arguments or have default values for all the arguments? Even if no defaults make sense.

Thanks very much for replying btw.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I missed that wrinkle first time around. Right now, ScalaMock3 can only mock traits and no-args classes. But if you control SocketClient, you should still be fine - create a trait which defines the methods and implement it in your class: trait SocketClientBase; class SocketClient(...) extends SocketClientBase. Then you can mock SocketClientBase and you should be good? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Also of note Even if I copy your code exactly I can't get it to compile. I get:

overriding method nestedSuites in trait SuiteMixin of type => scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[org.scalatest.Suite];
[error]  method nestedSuites in trait Suite of type => List[org.scalatest.Suite] has incompatible type
[error] class ScannerTest extends FunSuite with MockFactory {

Comment: That's seriously weird - I cut and paste the code in my answer directly from a working project. Which version of ScalaTest are you using? Can you make a project available (on GitHub?) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Ok I created an example project and put it on github: https://github.com/jangoolie/scalaMockExample

All I did was copy the code from your answer and add a build.sbt file.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was conflicting ScalaTest versions - ScalaMock3 depends on ScalaTest 2.0 or higher, and you were using 1.9.1. What I'm confused about is that sbt doesn't give any kind of warning about the conflict - I'll see if I can get the sbt guys to let me know why.

Comment: Yup that got it working. Now I just need to work out how to actually use mock objects... Thanks for all your help.