# How to mock a class with ScalaMock

Tags: scalamock

In the doc of ScalaMock, it is said that:

> mocking classes, traits and case classes

is one of the feature supported.

I have the following case class:

```
case class Thing(private val item: Item)
```

When I do:

```
val item = mock[Thing]
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> Error:(18, 24) not enough arguments for constructor Thing:
> ```

```
 (item: org.dspace.content.Item)org.iadb.poolpartyconnector.dspaceutils.Thing.
Unspecified value parameter item.
    val item = mock[Thing]
                   ^
```

I know I could implement an interface for it, but in any case, this would help me better understand how to mock a case class/a class that has a constructor.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274020/scalamock-mock-a-class-that-takes-arguments

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Currently, you cannot mock classes that do not have a default constructor defined.

You can workaround it by creating a subclass that has default constructor defined and mocking that subclass:

```
class MockableThing extends Thing(null)
val item = mock[MockableThing]
```

Comment: There's a feature request to make it possible: https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues/56

Comment: That feature request has now been merged, so it should be possible.